# IIS hosted WCF service creates thousands of temp folders

Tags: wcf, iis

I have an IIS-hosted WCF service, and yesterday I found out there were 66,235 folders (!!!) created in a temp folder 5 levels under the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" directory  (\234lkj\98734dc\assembly\tmp). Each one of those folders had exactly one of the dlls needed by the service, which only needs 6, so each dll was copied about 11,000 times on different folders. Does IIS copy them from the bin folder regardless of whether they change or not? Is this normal behaviour? Is there a configuration setting that will prevent IIS (or whatever process is doing it) from unnecessarily copying a dll?

Answer (score 0):

The temp folder is used by .NET to JIT compile references from other services.  .NET needs a place to create the files and then compiles this code to eventually work with the service.  Now, why you are seeing so many files may have more to do with how the application pool that hosts the site is set up.  If you look in the advanced settings for your application pool, look at how many worker processes are assigned.  Each worker process can exist with its own memory, so this would require multiple folders being JITed if multiple service references abound.  Also, check to make sure that process orphaning is not set to on.  If so, your processes can leave behind the files, causing the build up that you see.

Comment: I'm using the DefaultAppPool with Maximum Worker Processes = 2 and Process Orphaning->Enabled = False. I deleted all the temp folders four days ago, last time I checked there were about 2,000 new folders created. Come to think of it...why are those folders needed in the first place? I understand the role of the temp asp.net files, but in this service everything is already compiled, there are no source code files anywhere, it's just copying dlls blindly from one folder to another. Something's wrong......